# Interpreting kinesis iteratorAgeMilliseconds graph

Tags: amazon-kinesis

The image below shows the current and expected graphs for the iteratorAgeMilliseconds metric in kinesis.

1. The graph continues to rise even though no more data is added to kinesisn
2. If the amount consumed is greater than put, it was expected that the y value of the chart would gradually decrease. However, the chart appears in a cliff-like shape. Can you guess why?

[image]